# Correct way to a-synchronize parallel tasks

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

Currently we have this code which works fine:

```
Result result1 = null;
Result result2 = null;

var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
   var records = DB.Read("..");
   //Do A lot
   result1 = Process(records);  
}); 

var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
   var records = DB.Read(".....");
   //Do A lot
   result2 = Process(records);  
});

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

var result = Combine(result1, result2);
```

Now we would like to use async counterparts of DB Functions and we are using this new pattern:

```
Result result1 = null;
Result result2 = null;

var task1 = await Task.Factory.StartNew( async ()=>
{
   var records = await DB.ReadAsync("..");
   //Do A lot
   result1 = Process(records);  
}); 

var task2 = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async ()=>
{
   var records = await DB.ReadAsync(".....");
   //Do A lot
   result2 = Process(records);  
});

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

var result = Combine(result1, result2);
```

After we switched to async we started observing abnormal behavior. So I wonder if this is the correct pattern to parallelize async calls ?

Comment: What kind of abnormal behavior are you talking about specifically? Did the tasks intertwine with each other? Did the tasks not work properly?

Comment: Your `result`s should be task return values, not closure'd variables.  Return them from the tasks.

Comment: I guess the method which awaits on task1/2 will immediately return which could be called abnormal.

Comment: Basically I cannot walk through the code under debug. All of a sudden the code flow just takes off and completes the whole thing with errors

Comment: You should not add await on task1= AWAIT. We think that is the problem cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` is a pre-async API. You should be using `Task.Run` which was designed with async-await in mind:

```
var task1 = await Task.Run( async ()=>
{
   var records = await DB.ReadAsync("..");
   //Do A lot
   result1 = Process(records);  
});
```

The issue is that an async lambda returns a `Task` so `Task.Factory.StartNew` returns a `Task<Task>` (the outer one because `Task.Factory.StartNew` returns a `Task` and the inner one which is the result of the async lambda).

This means that when you wait on `task1` and `task2` you aren't really waiting for the entire operation, just the synchronous part of it.

You can fix that by using `Task.Unwrap` on the returned `Task<Task>`:

```
Task<Task> task1 = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async ()=>
{
   var records = await DB.ReadAsync("..");
   //Do A lot
   result1 = Process(records);  
});

Task actualTask1 = task1.Unwrap();
await actualTask1;
```

But `Task.Run` does that implicitly for you.

---

As a side note, you should realize that you don't need `Task.Run` to execute these operations concurrently. You can do that just by calling these methods and awaiting the results together with `Task.When`:

```
async Task MainAsync()
{
    var task1 = FooAsync();
    var task2 = BarAsync();
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

    var result = Combine(task1.Result, task2.Result);
}

async Task<Result> FooAsync()
{
    var records = await DB.ReadAsync("..");
    //Do A lot
    return Process(records);  
}

async Task<Result> BarAsync()
{
    var records = await DB.ReadAsync(".....");
    //Do A lot
    return Process(records);
}
```

You only need `Task.Run` if you need to offload even the synchronous parts of these methods (the part before the first `await`) to the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: Why not just use `await DB.ReadAsync()` without `Task.Run` wrappers?

Comment: @Noseratio: right, you still can. But, looks like, Op is more concerned about using `Task`, for some reason, then async call.

Comment: @Tigran, I'd use async APIs without wrapping and then wrap `Process` calls with `Task.Run` - if they're really CPU intensive.

Comment: @Noseratio: My point is: spinning up `Task` (thread) is relatively epxnsive operation, and considering that you need to do that *any way* (cause it's compute intensive), just do it upfront. More straightforward data management.

Comment: @Noseratio no reason. It just wasn't the OP's problem.

Comment: @i3arnon thank you your explanation seems reasonable. May I clarify what would I do to avoid Declaring Foo and Bar asyncs as separate methods. I would like to keep them within one method ?

Comment: @AstroSharp You can declare them as delegates and then invoke them, but it's less clean: `Func<Task<Result>> action1 = async () => ...; Task<Result> task1 = action1();`

Comment: The reason I observed an odd behavior is that I ran my project under Release. In this mode DLLs were optimized and I certain Debug symbols were not available in step-by-step execution. Nonetheless your reply brought me to a closer understanding to the Async pattern. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` start a new Task of execution another *independent* execution unit. So the simplest way to deal with that may look like:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> //NO AWAIT
{
   var records = DB.Read("....."); //NO ASYNC
   //Do A lot
   result1 = Process(records);  
});

... another task definition

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

Read and process *sequentially* in one task, as you have data dependency.

Comment: StartNew does not support async methods, it does not unwrap the inner task. You really should be using `Task.Run(` instead. Please read "[StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)" by Stepen Cleary

Comment: I don't use async method, as you might see if you read the code.

Comment: `var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async ()=> ` you use async right there. `task1` will be a `Task<Task>` and your `WaitAll` is not going to work like you expect it to. To use `WaitAll` like you want you first need to call `.Unwrap()` on the task (Or use `Task.Run(` which calls unwrap for you).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you are right. Writing from mobile and bad copy/paste of the code. That's not what I ment definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Well using .WaitAll is not an async programming because you're actually blocking current thread on waiting. Also you dont call .Unwrap and that's why you just wait only on creating of async lambda, not on async lambda itself.

Task.Run can unwrap async lambda for you. But there's a simpler and cleaner way.

```
var task1 = DB.ReadAsync("..").ContinueWith(task => {
   //Do A lot
   return Process(task.Result);  
}, TaskScheduler.Default);

var task2 = DB.ReadAsync("..").ContinueWith(task => {
   //Do A lot
   return Process(task.Result);  
}, TaskScheduler.Default);

var result = Combine(await task1, await task2);
```

In this way you will get result exactly when it's ready. So you don't need additional tasks and variables at all.

Please note that ContinueWith is a tricky function and it works on TaskScheduler.Current if it is not null and otherwise it works on TaskScheduler.Default which is thread pool scheduler. So it's safer to specify scheduler explicitly always when calling this function.

Also for claryfing I didn't included error checking because actually DB.ReadAsync can be completed with an error. But that's an easy thing and you can handle it for yourself.

Comment: The parameter in `ContinueWith` is antecedent `Task`.